# Why do I get this error installing mysql gem?

Tags: mysql, ruby

Whenever I run `gem install mysql`, I get a `Failed to build gem native extension error` telling me to to check `mkmf.log`. Here's what that file looks like:

```
have_library: checking for main() in -llibmysql... -------------------- no

"x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -o conftest.exe -Ic:/Ruby21-x64/include/ruby-2.1.0/x64-mingw32 -Ic:/Ruby21-x64/include/ruby-2.1.0/ruby/backward -Ic:/Ruby21-x64/include/ruby-2.1.0 -I. -DFD_SETSIZE=2048 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0501 -D__MINGW_USE_VC2005_COMPAT -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64   -O3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-fast-math -g -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wunused-variable -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wimplicit-function-declaration conftest.c  -L. -Lc:/Ruby21-x64/lib -L.      -lx64-msvcrt-ruby210  -lshell32 -lws2_32 -liphlpapi -limagehlp -lshlwapi  "
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2: 
3: #include <winsock2.h>
4: #include <windows.h>
5: int main(int argc, char **argv)
6: {
7:   return 0;
8: }
/* end */

"x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -o conftest.exe -Ic:/Ruby21-x64/include/ruby-2.1.0/x64-mingw32 -Ic:/Ruby21-x64/include/ruby-2.1.0/ruby/backward -Ic:/Ruby21-x64/include/ruby-2.1.0 -I. -DFD_SETSIZE=2048 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0501 -D__MINGW_USE_VC2005_COMPAT -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64   -O3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-fast-math -g -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wunused-variable -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wimplicit-function-declaration conftest.c  -L. -Lc:/Ruby21-x64/lib -L.      -lx64-msvcrt-ruby210 -llibmysql  -lshell32 -lws2_32 -liphlpapi -limagehlp -lshlwapi  "
conftest.c: In function 't':
conftest.c:16:32: warning: variable 'p' set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
c:/users/compy/desktop/ruby dev/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.2/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -llibmysql
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
checked program was:
/* begin */
 1: #include "ruby.h"
 2: 
 3: #include <winsock2.h>
 4: #include <windows.h>
 5: 
 6: /*top*/
 7: extern int t(void);
 8: int main(int argc, char **argv)
 9: {
10:   if (argc > 1000000) {
11:     printf("%p", &t);
12:   }
13: 
14:   return 0;
15: }
16: int t(void) { void ((*volatile p)()); p = (void ((*)()))main; return 0; }
/* end */

"x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -o conftest.exe -Ic:/Ruby21-x64/include/ruby-2.1.0/x64-mingw32 -Ic:/Ruby21-x64/include/ruby-2.1.0/ruby/backward -Ic:/Ruby21-x64/include/ruby-2.1.0 -I. -DFD_SETSIZE=2048 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0501 -D__MINGW_USE_VC2005_COMPAT -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64   -O3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-fast-math -g -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wunused-variable -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wimplicit-function-declaration conftest.c  -L. -Lc:/Ruby21-x64/lib -L.      -lx64-msvcrt-ruby210 -llibmysql  -lshell32 -lws2_32 -liphlpapi -limagehlp -lshlwapi  "
conftest.c: In function 't':
conftest.c:16:1: error: too few arguments to function 'main'
conftest.c:8:5: note: declared here
checked program was:
/* begin */
 1: #include "ruby.h"
 2: 
 3: #include <winsock2.h>
 4: #include <windows.h>
 5: 
 6: /*top*/
 7: extern int t(void);
 8: int main(int argc, char **argv)
 9: {
10:   if (argc > 1000000) {
11:     printf("%p", &t);
12:   }
13: 
14:   return 0;
15: }
16: int t(void) { main(); return 0; }
/* end */

--------------------
```

I'm on Windows 8, 64-bit version. I got `libmysql.dll` in `C:\Ruby21-x64\bin`. I've installed Connector/C for MySQL. I have MySQL running, too.

Why does this fail to install the `mysql` gem?

Answer (score 0):

So basically you are seeing a failure to build a native gem.
To build a native gem (this is on any OS btw) you need to have the right build tools and the dependencies you need installed.

Take a look at: http://rubyonwindowsguides.github.io/book/ch02-05.html

Also, for your specific case look at: 
https://github.com/luislavena/mysql-gem/issues/23